# Why is there a data type mismatch error in SSMS 18 while casting from datime to date in View Creation Dialog?

Tags: sql, t-sql, view, ssms

I encountered an issue while **creating a view** in SQLServer Management Studio 18.9.1 (EDIT: Create View Designer Dialog)
When entering a casting expression (from datetime column to date) in the Column "Column" it shows an error message: Data type mismatch - no conversion possible.

[image]

This same expression in a simple Select Query works without any issues.
I managed to get casting as datetime (same type) in the Create View window to verify that expressions work.
After some research, I found that most issue were with casting nvarchar to date or vice versa, but not datetime to date which should be always possible? What am I missing?

Comment: Where are you doing this? What do you actually do to create this error? Really though, just don't use the designers; they are clunky, lack functionality, and have a habit of generating errors for tasks that are simple when using T-SQL.

Comment: I know, but if we had to -> It's the Create view designer

Comment: "We had to", followed by describing a task (creating a view) that's reasonably straightforward to do with a `CREATE VIEW` statement in a query window, no designer required.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, Datum, 1)
```

ex (datetime):

```
SELECT Datum FROM testTable
```

[image]

fix (date):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), Datum, 1) FROM testTable
```

[image]

Create view:

```
CREATE VIEW testView 
AS
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), Datum, 1) as Datum FROM testTable
```

Comment: thanks. I can do this with T-SQL, the issue is the SSMS Designer